# How can I get Linqpad intellisense to show C# 5.0 methods?

Tags: c#, linqpad, c#-5.0

I use Linqpad as a code scratch pad to play with C# 5.0 async features. My code compiles and executes fine, but intellisense only shows elements from the 4.0 framework.

For example, there is `Task.WaitAll()` but no `Task.WhenAll()` or `Task.Delay()` in the suggestion list.

According to Joe Albahari, intellisense should work with .Net 4.5, but I could not get it running.

I tried it on different machines running different combinations of Windows 7 and Windows 8 (RC & RTM) and VS 2012 Beta, RC and Final.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Joe about this? Might be better to ask him directly.

Comment: Yes, I did. He could not reproduce the issue. The intellisense worked as expected (i.e. showing the 4.5 methods) for him.

Comment: What version are you using, Joe details it as "LINQPad supports everything in C# 4.0/5.0 and Framework 4"

Comment: I am using v4.42.01 of LINQPad, but also tried other versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joseph Albahari was able to locate the source of the problem and fixed it in the new Beta release.

http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx